# Compute function for n<-1:1000

Tags: r, function, integer

I use `CRRBinomialTreeOption` function to compute the price of a put option (pe). Actually, the price should be computed for each "n", i.e., the output should be 1000 prices.

```
library('fOptions')
n<-1:1000
CRRBinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag ="pe", 100, 90,
                    3, 0.05, 0, 0.077, n, title = NULL, description = NULL)
```

When I run the aforementioned function, I get this error `Error in seq.default(from = n - 1, to = 0, by = -1) : 
  'from' must be of length 1` .

Comment: `n <- 1000; ...` or (eventually you want) `sapply(1:1000, function(n) CRRBinomialTreeOption(TypeFlag ="pe", 100, 90,
                    3, 0.05, 0, 0.077, n, title = NULL, description = NULL))`

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fOptions/versions/3042.86/topics/BinomialTreeOptions `n` should be a single number (as it says in your error message). Use `1000` instead of the vector `1:1000`.

Comment: Like others have point it out, there is no need to do a sequence. ``n`` is a single number (``number of time steps; an integer value.``) in this function. It should work fine with @jogo's code.

Comment: @jogo thank you very much, it works